# define simple function to use in all view (laravel4.2)

Tags: laravel-4

i have a getCategory function in my controller:

```
  function getCategory($id){
                $category=UserBlogCategory::find($id);
                return $category->name;
            }
```

and i want to use to my view:

```
echo getCategory($user_blog->category_id);
```

and i get this error:
Call to undefined function getCategory()

i already put getCategory in view and it was worked, but i want to use myfunction in any part of my project.

Comment: that function must be in your model as static function, then write `use` of your model in the view and call it with `mymodel::`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function must be in your model as static function, then write `use` of your model in the view and call it with `mymodel::`